# Excel, i have a big list (44000 records), i would like to sepperate them into 2 lists, 1 with unique values and 1 with duplicate value's

Tags: excel

My list looks somewhat like this:

```
1. Unique1
2. double1
3. double2
4. unique2
5. double1
6. unique3
7. double2
8. unique4
9. double3
10. double4
```

and so on..

My wanted output:

list 1

```
 1.unique1
 2.unique2
 3.unique3
 4.unique4
```

list 2

```
 1.double1
 2.double2
 3.double3
 4.double4
```

I've only found things like remove/hilight duplicates or count/hilight unique values. But I need to display the values in another list.

Comment: You need to provide some example of your work around.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete 
Sorry, What do you mean with workaround? 
First time i'm asking something here.

My work around plan for now is to do it manually :D

Comment: I've got a list now that looks something like this:

1. double1

2. double2

3. double1

4. double3

5. double2

6. double4

when i try and use remove duplicates function i end up with just the unique value's

1. double3

2. double4

but i want 1 value of each..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a PivotTable out of the data. Put the field of interest in it as both a Row Field and as a Values field, and make sure that the aggregation being applied is a Count. (It will be by default if your things are text).

Anything with a Count of 1 is unique. Anything with a count > 1 is not.

[image]

You can then optionally copy the PivotTable, and set a Values filter to show where the count = 1 in one, and count > 1 in the other, like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jeffreyweir! I will try and do this today, i'll let you know if it solved my problem, but it sure looks like what i need!

Comment: This was indeed the best way to solve my problem!
Thanks alot!

Comment: Cool. It's incredible what you can do with PivotTables. A large number of the questions on SO that ask for code or formulas to filter data or dedupe it can be solved with a PivotTable.