# How to find 1st, 2nd, 3rd most occuring text string in Excel using functions?

Tags: excel, function, frequency

I am really having troubles with this one:

In one column, I have a long list of company names. The company names appear several times (based on how many tickets they have raised, but that is another story).

I am now looking for a function that would give me the Company name that occurs the most often. In the Cell below I would like to get company name that occurs the second most often. In the Cell below the company that occurs the third most often end so on and so on.

I thank everyone who is spending some time to help me figure this out.
Stephan

Comment: seems like an exact dupe of [Excel: Find most frequent occurring value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904207/excel-find-most-frequent-occurring-value-in-a-range) but I used the wrong flag at first, so someone else would need to tag it

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Make a PivotTable out of the data. Put the field of interest in it as both a Row Field and as a Values field, and make sure that the aggregation being applied is a Count. (It will be by default if your things are text).

See my answer at [Excel, i have a big list (44000 records), i would like to sepperate them into 2 lists, 1 with unique values and 1 with duplicate value's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855554/excel-i-have-a-big-list-44000-records-i-would-like-to-sepperate-them-into-2/49867843#49867843)